# Avoid "Nullable value type may be null" warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm getting a [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8629)#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference) of `Nullable value type may be null` in a lambda but the previous statement was `.Where(o => o.HasValue)` so, no, the value type cannot be null. How an I tell Visual Studio to not flag these false positives?

For example:

```
var list = new List<int?> { 1, 2, null, 3 };
var query = list
    .Where(o => o.HasValue)
    .Select(o => o.Value);
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Nullable reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types)

Comment: You could [suppress the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings), though personally I think it's less invasive to just do what the page you linked suggests and use the null-coalescing operator to provide a sensible default, even if that default will never logically be used at runtime.  Or perhaps the null-forgiving operator (also suggested by the page you linked).

Comment: You can use the null forgiving operator as linked: `.Where(o => o.HasValue).Select(o => o!.Value)`

Comment: @David The reason the `.Where(o => o.HasValue)` exists is to filter out the non-nulls before doing anymore work so to then suggest that the nulls are being addressed in a second way seems misleading.

Comment: The null forgiving operator seems to work but feels hacky. Like, VS should be able to figure out that it's not possible for that warning to be relevant where it is placing the warning. It's unfortunate if I have to be responsible for adding `!`.

Comment: @Brad: Which may indeed be true, but the warning is simply the compiler indicating that *it* doesn't guarantee this.  If *you* guarantee this then you can certainly suppress the warning.  (Which I guess is the answer to the question of how to "tell Visual Studio to not flag them".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler won't execute your Linq expression.

The `Where()` is opaque to it and whatever you write within the expression passed to `Where()` won't change `Where()`'s return value, so your `Select()` still operates on an `IEnumerable<int?>`.

You could as well write `Where(o => true)` or `Where(o => false)`, it won't change the *type* of the collection going into or coming out of it.

The solution is to tell the compiler where *you* know the values won't be null anymore:

```
.Select(o => o!.Value);
```

The `!` after `o` merely tells the compiler: "trust me, I know `o` is not null here".

Comment: An unfortunate compromise but it works. Going back and forth between C# and Typescript, it seems like Typescript would figure this out.