# Type conversion error CS0029 when filtering list of nullable enums using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion, nullable

This code compiles just fine:

```
public record Foo
(
    double X
);


private static void Test()
{
    IImmutableList<Foo?> myList = ImmutableList<Foo?>.Empty.Add(new Foo(42)).Add(null);
    IImmutableList<Foo> myCleanedList = myList.Where(foo => foo is not null).ToImmutableList();
}
```

But this one doesn't:

```
public enum FooEnum
{
    ONE,
    TWO
}

private static void Test()
{
    IImmutableList<FooEnum?> myEnumList = ImmutableList<FooEnum?>.Empty.Add(FooEnum.ONE).Add(null);
    IImmutableList<FooEnum> myCleanedEnumList = myEnumList.Where(foo => foo is not null).ToImmutableList();
}
```

I get a compiler error

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<MyTestDummy.FooEnum?>` to `System.Collections.Immutable.IImmutableList<MyTestDummy.FooEnum>`

Why is that and how do I make it go away?

For context: in my specific production use case the method `Test` has a return type of `IImmutableList<FooEnum>`, so I am forced to filter out the null values and cannot change the return type.

Comment: `Where(foo => foo is not null).Select(foo => foo.Value)`.

Comment: Ouch. I hope my stupidity helps others. Do you mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: I'm trying to find a duplicate, but can't...

Comment: My stupidity cannot be matched nor duplicated. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently answered [Avoid "Nullable value type may be null" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75617729/avoid-nullable-value-type-may-be-null-warning) which is related to this, but the point is: nullable *reference* types mainly issue compiler warnings, while nullable *value* types are in themselves a wholly different type: `Nullable<T>`. And `T != Nullable<T>`.

So you'll have to get each value out of the source, for example using a `Select()`:

```
.Where(foo => foo is not null).Select(foo => foo!.Value).ToImmutableList();
```